# RandBetween function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write my first lines using VBA and I don't know why I can't use Randbetween() function and I get the error "Sub or Function not defined"

Comment: `x = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(2, 10)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.randbetween

Answer (score 2):

In many forms of BASIC, including vba - whether Word, Excel, Access etc., you have the built in Function `Rnd()`. (see Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rnd-function))

In it's simplest form, it will generate a random value between 0 and 1 - e.g. 0.7055475.

So if you wanted to generate a random number (integer) between two integers, you could use the following:

```
num = Int ((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)
```

So when looking for a random number between 5 and 50, you would use:

```
num = Int ((50 - 5 + 1) * Rnd + 5)
```

Alternatively, because you're using Excel - you can use the `RandBetween` function that is usable within cells. To utilise cell functions, you need to precede the function with `WorkSheetFunction.` like so:

```
num = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(5, 50)
```